# Find Line integral of $e^{-z} /{z-\pi/2}$ on a region $\gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration

Let $\gamma$ be the diamond connecting points $x=2, -2$ and $y=2, -2$.  and its oriented positively (counter-clockwise, I believe?).  I'm not so sure if we can use the Cauchy integral formula here and just say that our answer is $2\pi i e^{-\pi i/2}$.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Residue Theorem?

Comment: I don't think I've learned that yet.  Is there another way to do this problem?

Comment: Can you use the fact that integrals over homotopic paths are equivalent if the function is holomorphic everywhere inbetween? If not, then I'm not sure I would try to explicitely calculate it from the definition of integral over complex functions.

Comment: Well, can you show me?  I'm just not sure what theorem to use.

Comment: I'm not sure of the best way to find the answer. I would just use the residue theorem and be done with it, but if not do you happen to know the strict definition of a complex line integral? If not look in a book or look online somewhere.

Comment: perhaps you're right.  I'll look into the residue theorem.

Comment: Can't you use the fact that $\pi/2$ lies inside $\gamma$? Knowing this, you can apply Cauchy's integral formula to get the value $2\pi i e^{-\pi/2}$.

Comment: @kobe the contour is not a disc though. That's why I said you need to use the fact about homotopic paths.

Comment: Actually can you show me how to use the residue formula.  I'm not so sure I know how its applied.

Comment: @MatthewLevy $\gamma$ need not be a disk to apply the formula, but a simple closed contour.

Comment: So is my way of approaching this problem correct or not?

Comment: @kobe guess it depends on what book you read. Obviously its true if you know the theorem about homotopic paths and holomorphic functions, but the Cauchy's formula is first proved for a disc and then you use the above theorem to prove it for arbitrary simple closed contours. I don't know how much the OP has been taught though so I didn't want to suggest overkill.

Comment: @cambelot Find all the singularities of your function that lie inside the contous, then calculate the residues at these points... come on look in your book or use google.

Comment: @MatthewLevy I don't think you were suggesting overkill, although I'm not sure how using the residue theorem is less overkill than using the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: @kobe its more overkill that's why I asked first.

Comment: got it.  Its still the same answer I believe.  But does the orientation make it negative?